# Conventional C# for LinkedList with (non-)nullable references + xunit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, null, xunit, nullable-reference-types

I'm new to C# and would appreciate any feedback you might have on the following doubly-linked list implementation, particularly WRT the following language features:

- Exception handling
- Debug.Assert
- [Null state attributes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) (e.g. `MaybeNullWhen`)
- The Try pattern with `out` params
- Test style with `xunit`
- Anything else that looks "weird" or unconventional

Thanks very much for your time! <3

Imlementation:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace DataStructures
{
    public class LinkedList<T>
    {
        public LinkedList(T val)
        {
            Add(val);
        }

        public LinkedList()
        {
        }

        public LinkedListNode<T>? HeadNode { get; set; }

        public LinkedListNode<T>? TailNode { get; set; }

        public int Count { get; private set; }

        public T GetHead()
        {
            return HeadNode is null ? throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(HeadNode)) : HeadNode.Val;
        }

        public T GetTail()
        {
            return TailNode is null ? throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(TailNode)) : TailNode.Val;
        }

        public T Add(T val, int? index = null)
        {
            return index switch
            {
                null => AddLast(val),
                0 => AddFirst(val),
                _ => index == Count ? AddLast(val) : AddToMiddle(val, index.Value)
            };
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            HeadNode = null;
            TailNode = null;
            Count = 0;
        }

        public T GetAt(int index)
        {
            return GetNodeAt(index).Val;
        }

        public T RemoveAt(int index)
        {
            ValidateIndex(index);
            return Remove(GetNodeAt(index));
        }

        public bool TryRemoveFor(Predicate<T> predicate, [ MaybeNullWhen(false) ] out T removed)
        {
            if (TryFindNode(predicate, out LinkedListNode<T>? node))
            {
                removed = Remove(node);
                return true;
            }

            removed = default;
            return false;
        }

        public bool TryFind(Predicate<T> predicate, [ MaybeNullWhen(false) ] out T found)
        {
            if (TryFindNode(predicate, out LinkedListNode<T>? foundNode))
            {
                found = foundNode.Val;
                return true;
            }

            found = default;
            return false;
        }

        bool TryFindNode(Predicate<T> predicate, [ NotNullWhen(true) ] out LinkedListNode<T>? node)
        {
            node = HeadNode;
            while (node != null)
            {
                if (predicate(node.Val)) return true;
                node = node.Next;
            }

            return false;
        }

        LinkedListNode<T> GetNodeAt(int index)
        {
            ValidateIndex(index);

            Debug.Assert(TailNode != null, "The linked list should be non-empty");
            if (index == Count - 1)
            {
                return TailNode;
            }

            Debug.Assert(HeadNode != null, "The linked list should be non-empty");
            LinkedListNode<T> node = HeadNode;
            for (var i = 0; i != index; i++)
            {
                Debug.Assert(node != null, "All nodes within the linked list must be defined");
                Debug.Assert(node.Next != null, "This loop shouldn't run for the last entry in the linked list");
                node = node.Next;
            }

            return node;
        }

        T Remove(LinkedListNode<T> node)
        {
            if (node.Prev is null)
            {
                HeadNode = node.Next;
            }
            else
            {
                node.Prev.Next = node.Next;
            }

            if (node.Next is null)
            {
                TailNode = node.Prev;
            }
            else
            {
                node.Next.Prev = node.Prev;
            }

            Count--;
            if (Count <= 1) HeadNode = TailNode = HeadNode ?? TailNode;

            return node.Val;
        }

        T AddFirst(T val)
        {
            if (HeadNode is null) return AddLast(val);

            var newNode = new LinkedListNode<T>(val);
            HeadNode.Prev = newNode;
            HeadNode = newNode;
            Count++;
            return newNode.Val;
        }

        T AddToMiddle(T val, int index)
        {
            ValidateIndex(index, 1);
            var newNode = new LinkedListNode<T>(val);
            LinkedListNode<T> toShift = GetNodeAt(index);
            LinkedListNode<T>? precedingNode = toShift.Prev;
            Debug.Assert(precedingNode != null, "index should not refer to the head");

            precedingNode.Next = newNode;
            newNode.Prev = precedingNode;
            toShift.Prev = newNode;
            newNode.Next = toShift;
            Count++;
            return val;
        }


        T AddLast(T val)
        {
            var newNode = new LinkedListNode<T>(val);
            if (HeadNode is null)
            {
                HeadNode = TailNode = newNode;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Assert(TailNode != null, "Head and tail should both be either null or non-null");

                TailNode.Next = newNode;
                newNode.Prev = TailNode;
                TailNode = newNode;
            }

            Count++;
            return newNode.Val;
        }

        void ValidateIndex(int index, int lowerBoundInclusive = 0)
        {
            if (index >= lowerBoundInclusive ||
                index < Count)
            {
                return;
            }

            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(index));
        }
    }

    public class LinkedListNode<T>
    {
        public LinkedListNode(T val, LinkedListNode<T>? prev = null, LinkedListNode<T>? next = null)
        {
            Val = val;
            Prev = prev;
            Next = next;
        }

        public LinkedListNode<T>? Next { get; set; }

        public LinkedListNode<T>? Prev { get; set; }

        public T Val { get; }
    }
}
```

Tests:

````
using System;
using DataStructures;
using Xunit;

namespace TestDataStructures
{
    public class LinkedListTest
    {
        const int TestValue = -100;

        [ Fact ]
        public void InitializeEmptyTest()
        {
            var ll = new LinkedList<int>();
            Assert.Equal(0, ll.Count);
            Assert.Null(ll.HeadNode!);
            Assert.Null(ll.TailNode!);
            Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => ll.GetHead());
            Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => ll.GetTail());
        }

        [ Fact ]
        public void InitializeNonEmptyTest()
        {
            var ll = new LinkedList<int>(TestValue);
            Assert.Equal(1, ll.Count);
            Assert.NotNull(ll.HeadNode!);
            Assert.NotNull(ll.TailNode!);
            Assert.Equal(TestValue, ll.GetHead());
            Assert.Equal(TestValue, ll.GetTail());
        }

        [ Fact ]
        public void AddTest()
        {
            const int numToAdd = 5;
            var ll = new LinkedList<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < numToAdd; i++)
            {
                int added = ll.Add(i);
                Assert.Equal(i, added);
            }

            LinkedListNode<int>? node = ll.HeadNode;
            for (var i = 0; i < numToAdd; i++)
            {
                Assert.Equal(i, node?.Val);
                node = node?.Next;
            }

            Assert.Equal(numToAdd, ll.Count);
        }

        [ Theory ]
        [ InlineData(0, 0) ]
        [ InlineData(3, 0) ]
        [ InlineData(3, 1) ]
        [ InlineData(3, 2) ]
        [ InlineData(5, 3) ]
        [ InlineData(3, 3) ]
        public void AddAtIndexTest(int collectionSize, int? insertIndex = null)
        {
            var ll = new LinkedList<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
            {
                ll.Add(i);
            }

            int added = ll.Add(TestValue, insertIndex);
            Assert.Equal(TestValue, added);

            LinkedListNode<int>? node = ll.HeadNode;
            for (var i = 0; i != insertIndex; i++)
            {
                node = node?.Next;
            }

            Assert.Equal(TestValue, node?.Val);
            Assert.Equal(collectionSize + 1, ll.Count);
        }

        [ Fact ]
        public void ClearTest()
        {
            const int numToAdd = 3;
            var ll = new LinkedList<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < numToAdd; i++)
            {
                int added = ll.Add(i);
                Assert.Equal(i, added);
            }

            ll.Clear();
            Assert.Equal(0, ll.Count);
            Assert.Null(ll.HeadNode!);
            Assert.Null(ll.TailNode!);
            Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => ll.GetHead());
            Assert.Throws<InvalidOperationException>(() => ll.GetTail());
        }

        [ Theory ]
        [ InlineData(0, 3) ]
        [ InlineData(1, 3) ]
        [ InlineData(2, 3) ]
        public void GetAtTest(int getIndex, int collectionSize)
        {
            var ll = new LinkedList<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
            {
                ll.Add(i);
            }

            int got = ll.GetAt(getIndex);
            Assert.Equal(getIndex, got);
        }

        [ Theory ]
        [ InlineData(3, 0, 0) ]
        [ InlineData(3, 1, 1) ]
        [ InlineData(3, 2, 2) ]
        [ InlineData(3, 3) ]
        [ InlineData(3, -1) ]
        public void TryFindTest(int collectionSize, int toCompare, int? expected = null)
        {
            bool Predicate(int i)
            {
                return i == toCompare;
            }

            var ll = new LinkedList<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
            {
                ll.Add(i);
            }

            bool wasFound = ll.TryFind(Predicate, out int got);
            Assert.Equal(expected.HasValue, wasFound);
            Assert.Equal(expected ?? default, got);
        }

        [ Theory ]
        [ InlineData(0, 3) ]
        [ InlineData(1, 3) ]
        [ InlineData(2, 3) ]
        [ InlineData(2, 5) ]
        public void RemoveAtTest(int removeIndex, int collectionSize)
        {
            var ll = new LinkedList<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
            {
                ll.Add(i);
            }

            int got = ll.RemoveAt(removeIndex);
            Assert.Equal(removeIndex, got);
            Assert.Equal(collectionSize - 1, ll.Count);
        }

        [ Theory ]
        [ InlineData(3, 0, 0) ]
        [ InlineData(3, 1, 1) ]
        [ InlineData(3, 2, 2) ]
        [ InlineData(3, 3) ]
        [ InlineData(3, -1) ]
        public void RemoveForTest(int collectionSize, int toCompare, int? expected = null)
        {
            bool Predicate(int i)
            {
                return i == toCompare;
            }

            var ll = new LinkedList<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < collectionSize; i++)
            {
                ll.Add(i);
            }

            bool wasFound = ll.TryRemoveFor(Predicate, out int got);
            Assert.Equal(expected.HasValue, wasFound);
            Assert.Equal(expected ?? default, got);
            Assert.Equal(wasFound ? collectionSize - 1 : collectionSize, ll.Count);
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: If someone with 300+ rep could create the `nullable-reference-types` tag I'll add it to this question. [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nullable-reference-types) has the feature tagged with that name, so best to keep it the same.

Comment: Please don't edit the question after it has been answered, especially the code. Everyone must be able to view the code as the original reviewer did.

Comment: @pacmaninbw Ah, I left the original question's code alone and just added a new section with the updated code according to the feedback I got, the header explained this. I've seen that done on stack overflow, but if it's frowned upon I'll not do it again.

Comment: For more information, please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast Great post, thanks for that! I'll be sure not to edit the question in this way again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this review I'll focus on the implementation.

#### `LinkedList`

I have two problem with this name:

- It is a **doubly** linked list
- There is a [built-in BCL class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1) with same name

I would highly recommend you to scrutinize the built-in class before you start to re-invent the wheel.

Just to name a few things:

- There is a ctor which can receive an `IEnumerable`

  - This is a really powerful feature to help integrate with other collections
- `CopyTo` is yet again an extremely useful method from integration perspective
- There are methods like `AddAfter`, `AddBefore` which can ease the usage

  - Because we do not need to know the index
- `GetEnumerator` provides the ability to use `foreach` loops

  - In your case `GetForwardXYZ` and `GetBackwardXYZ` would make sense also

In case of doubly linked list it might not make too much sense to expose things like: `Head` and `Tail`. Their meaning are true only in case of forward iteration. But if you provide backward iteration as well their semantics break.

#### `LinkedListNode`

`LinkedListNode` yet again this is also a [built-in type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlistnode-1)

- It has a really useful property called `List`

  - This give you a pointer to that LinkedList where this node belongs

Unnecessary abbreviations:

- `T val` >> `T value`
- `Prev` >> `Previous`

IMO these are just making your API look weird.

- If you don’t need to abbreviate then don’t do that

---

#### `GetHead` / `GetTail`

- Personally I prefer this kind of one-liners:

  - **if** data is present **then** return that one **otherwise** fallback
- In case of C# 9:

```cs
 public T GetHead() => HeadNode is not null ? HeadNode.Val : throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(HeadNode));
```

- In case of C# 8:

```cs
public T GetHead() => HeadNode?.Val ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(nameof(HeadNode));
```

- Please bear in mind that this could work only if you restrict `T` either to `struct` or `class`

#### `Add`

- I think instead of `int? index = null` I would use `int? index = default`

  - It expresses the intent in a bit more clear way
- I would split your default case in your switch expression like this:

```cs
public T Add(T val, int? index = null)
    => index switch
    {
        null => AddLast(val),
        0 => AddFirst(val),
        _ when index == Count => AddLast(val),
        _ => AddToMiddle(val, index.Value)
    };
```

- Maybe it might make sense to split this method into two: `Add` and `AddAt`

#### `TryRemoveFor`, `TryFind`

- They had a huge resemblance, it might make sense to have a common ground
- I’m not really a huge fan of naming like `Predicate<T> predicate`

  - I prefer names like `nodeSelector`, `nodeValueMatcher`, etc.

#### `GetNodeAt` / `Remove`

- `node.Next` might have null, because it has a public setter that means you can easily have `NullReferenceException` here
- Same applies to `node.Prev.Next` and `node.Next.Prev`

#### `ValidateIndex`

- Even though `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` does not have a ctor where you can specify the allowed range, I do recommend to provide helpful error message, something like this:

> The allowed range is [0…n], the provided index is n+3. Please try to provide
> index inside the range.

Comment: Thanks very much, there's some great advice here! I'll make some changes.

I'll edit the original post to make it clear that this was just a code exercise and I'm not intending to use this implementation in an application. I would definitely use `System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList` in that case.

Comment: WRT `TryRemoveFor` and `TryFind`, good point they are super similar. I merged them but then decided to pull them apart again - they're pretty simple functions and not much was saved by having a common base. I often wait until I have 3 repetitions before refactoring, anyways.

WRT the potential `NullReferenceExceptions`, yes good point! I added some exceptions to the code, but I guess if I wanted to do this properly I would add safety guards to ensure consumers couldn't inject null nodes to the middle of the list.